# Android: Take the next playing card of a stapel effect

Tags: java, android, imagebutton, effect, sliding

I want that the user of my application has the effect of taking the next card from a stapel. So the user should take the next card with touching the card and sliding the topmost playing card to the left, out of the screen. How do I get to this effect?

I searched for examples but I could not find some, I think I don't have the right word to search for. I only found the ViewFlipper or the SlidingDrawer but I do not think that they help me with my problem. Maybe it is an animation, but the effect should react when the users lose the card.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple:
The stack of cards is just an image you draw your self. On a click event in your SurfaceView you show an extra image and let this move with the finger. Now it looks like the user picked an image from the stack. Also you have to see how big this moving card should be to make it visible for the user that it has a card linked to its finger.
Success
Jasper

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to draw the card image directly upon the stack and let all the logic of the effect reside on the card instead of splitting it between the stack and the card?